# Make Flask use Postgres on Heroku

Tags: postgresql, heroku, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

i have been following the Flask book by Miguel Ginberg and I am thinking about how to deploy my app and use the PostgresDB.

In my local production config I have to manually go in and run Role.insert_roles() before any roles can be assigned.

How do I do this in Heroku with postgres? In fact, how do you connect to the postgres db? It is not really clear where in the code postgres takes over using the environment variable:

https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/flasky/blob/master/config.py

I have a feeling my app is just running sqlite and the book isn't really clear on how to switch over.

SOLUTION:
if you have deployed to heroku and you have not changed the environment variables:

- DATABASE_URI to SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI
- FLASK_CONFIG = heroku
- FLASKY_ADMIN = your email

then ran in your shell:

```
heroku run python manage.py shell
db.create_all()
db.commit()
Role.insert_roles()
```

then you are probably running the development config from the SQLite database!

Comment: The tutorial uses [Flask-SQLAlchemy](http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-SQLAlchemy/). You'll have to change `SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI` to point to your Postgres database.

Comment: Ok, can you run the python shell in production when the database is set up right? Unless you write the roles to the database the administrator account based on your environment variable for email address is not properly configured.   `python manage.py shell` then  `role.create_all()`. How would you do this in heroku?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to connect manually, you could use the http://initd.org/psycopg/ libarary directly. [Flask-SQLAlchemy](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-SQLAlchemy/) provides uses psycopg underneath the hood itself, see [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/engines.html#postgresql) - in your example it may be easier to continue using SQLAlchemy. More information [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/postgresql.html).

Comment: the flask tutorial gives a command line option for a shell with Flask-SQL alchemy objects available. It is required to run Role.insert_roles() within this shell for every DB to write the user roles to the table. The book makes no explanation how this might be done in heroku.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved like the follow:
1. provisioning a db
    $:heroku addons:create heroku-postgresql bobby-dev
        ......
    add database_url:
    $:hero config -s |grep HEROKU-PSOTGRESQL
 ( then show HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_RED_URL=..... )
    $:heroku pg:promote HEROKU-POSTGRESQL-RED

2. install this extention:psycopg2

3.change the config.py:
config = {
         .....
         'default' : ProductionConfig
         }